# How to change bg image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an app in which I want to set an image background to my Canvas. Is it possible? If yes how?
I've tried a lot of things but work. Here is the code

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

bg=PhotoImage(file="bgbg.jpg")


canvas1 = Canvas(root, image=bg,width = 400, height = 800)
canvas1.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import module
from tkinter import *

# Create object
root = Tk()

# Adjust size
root.geometry("400x400")

# Add image file
bg = PhotoImage(file = "Your_img.png")

# Create Canvas
canvas1 = Canvas( root, width = 400,
                height = 400)

canvas1.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)

# Display image
canvas1.create_image( 0, 0, image = bg,
                    anchor = "nw")

# Add Text
canvas1.create_text( 200, 250, text = "Welcome")

# Create Buttons
button1 = Button( root, text = "Exit")
button3 = Button( root, text = "Start")
button2 = Button( root, text = "Reset")

# Display Buttons
button1_canvas = canvas1.create_window( 100, 10,
                                    anchor = "nw",
                                    window = button1)

button2_canvas = canvas1.create_window( 100, 40,
                                    anchor = "nw",
                                    window = button2)

button3_canvas = canvas1.create_window( 100, 70, anchor = "nw",
                                    window = button3)

# Execute tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It finally works. I went everywhere imaginable and unimaginable to know how it is done. Thanks a lot @Hamdi Mahmoud

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Sorry for the late answer
Tkinter PhotoImage only supports the GIF, PGM, PPM, and PNG file formats see [PythonDocs](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-photoimage/)

If u wanna use .jpeg then u have to use PIL. I changed a few lines at the bottom and it will work with .jpeg (for me)

Try this code.
U need a .png-picture

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

bg=PhotoImage(file="picture.png")


canvas1 = Canvas(root,width = 400, height = 800,bg='red')
canvas1.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

canvas1.create_image((200,400),image=bg,) # (200,400) are x and y cordinates.

root.mainloop()
```

u need a .jpeg-picture

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root=Tk()

image = Image.open("picture.jpeg")
bg= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


canvas1 = Canvas(root,width = 400, height = 800,bg='red')
canvas1.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

canvas1.create_image((200,400),image=bg,) # (200,400) are x and y cordinates.

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives an error

Comment: @Aaryan What is the error

Comment: Traceback(mostrecent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py",line 4, in <module>
    bg=PhotoImage(file="bgbg.jpg")
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4074, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4019, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image','create', imgtype, name,)+options)
_tkinter.TclError:couldn't open "bgbg.jpg":no such file or directory

Comment: I even tried png files. But doesn't work

Comment: @Aaryan is there a file name`bgbg.jpg` 'cause the error says there is no file or directory of this name.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Import the required library
from tkinter import *

YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"

#Create root
root= Tk()
root.title("My Title")
#define geometry
root.geometry("400x800")

#Load the image
background= PhotoImage(file="example.png")

#Create a canvas
canvas= Canvas(root,width= 400, height= 800)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill= BOTH)

#Add the image in the canvas  -> "nw" = start "North West"
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=background, anchor="nw")
#Add a text in canvas
canvas.create_text(200,400,text="It Works", font= ('Courier 45 bold'), fill=YELLOW)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).